# Can we use average aggregate instead of Sum for higher levels in Sunburst chart

Tags: highcharts, sunburst-diagram

I have data which needs to average out while drilling up in Sunburst. Right now its summing up data to the next level from lower level. Is there an option where it can be averaged rather than summed up.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sunburst

Is there any options I can add to make it average than sum up

```
series: [{
    type: "sunburst",
    data: data,
    stacking: 'percent',
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
        format: '{point.name}',
        filter: {
            property: 'innerArcLength',
            operator: '>',
            value: 16
        }
    },
    levels: [{
        level: 1,
        levelIsConstant: false,
        dataLabels: {
            filter: {
                property: 'outerArcLength',
                operator: '>',
                value: 64
            }
        }
    }, {
        level: 2,
        colorByPoint: true
    },
    {
        level: 3,
        colorVariation: {
            key: 'brightness',
            to: -0.5
        }
    }, {
        level: 4,
        colorVariation: {
            key: 'brightness',
            to: 0.5
        }
    }]

}],
```

Comment: Hi Veera S, Could you describe what you want to achieve more accurately? Also, some visual mockup would be very useful.

Comment: Hello, what I want to do is, rollup based on average rather than sum. For my Level 1, instead of summing up values from all the childs, I want an average.

Comment: Hi Veera S, Ok, but I still do not understand how it would look graphically. Please create some visual mockup.

Comment: For anyone facing this problem, I suggest to do the average manually and set the value property of the node.